# Does CELL_TYPE_BLANK works for hssf or xls files?

Tags: apache-poi, poi-hssf, hssf

I wanna ask that does CELL_TYPE_BLANK works for hssf or xls file system? I knw it works for xlsx or XSSF but i'm having problem with xls?

Comment: Which problem do you have exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want complete certainty then you can use this code:

```
 for(Row blankRow : sheet)
    {
     for(int cn = 0; cn < blankRow.getLastCellNum(); cn++) 
        {
            Cell cells = blankRow.getCell(cn, Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
        }
    }
```

It marks all the null spaces as blank and then the CELL_TYPE_BLANK works like it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. But take note that CELL_TYPE_`BLANK` is no `null`. You should always check first if the cell is `null` before identifying the cell type.